# Using FB.ui for "apprequest" and "feed" - JS error - c is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, feed, facebook-ui

I have developed two applications with `FB.ui()` calls to send app requests and ask to post status update with the "feed" parameters. It worked fine for several months, but for the past week I have been encountering error :

> c is undefined line 18 :
>   FB.provide('Dom',{containsCss:function...(oldonload);}else
>   oldonload();};})(); File : all.js

It's from the file all.js I import to use FB object from the url : http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js (i also tried http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js)

This is the part of the code which causes the error :

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    if(jsonRedirection.redirect == false) {

        FB.init({
          appId  : FBappId,
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
        });

    } 

});

function addFriends()
{
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Test'
        },
        function(response) {
            if(response != null) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I check my appId and I have the "fb-root" div before I call my addFriends function ...

Comment: Here's a simple example based on what you provided: http://fbrell.com/saved/58a66f765babcdd3d7b452afe02b4e41 -- works fine for me. Maybe you can provide some more details?

Answer (score 1):

"c is undefined" - This occurs due to mootools conflict. 
In uncompressed mootools file, there is a function " Function.implement({ ".  You can solve the issue by hiding this.

Let me know, If you get this work.

To be exact.
With In, Function.implement({
there will be a "create: function(options){" .
Just rename 'create' by 'Create'. ie., Make C - capital letter.
I Hope, this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the Function prototype..

```
Function.implement({
extend: function(properties){
    for (var property in properties) this[property] = properties[property];
    return this;
},

create: function(options){
```

And FB SDK function:

```
create:function(c,h){var e=window.FB,d=c?c.split('.'):[],a=d.length;for(var b=0;b<a;b++){var g=d[b];var f=e[g];if(!f){f=(h&&b+1==a)?h:{};e[g]=f;}e=f;}return e;}
```

**Solution:** In mootools, Rename "create" to "create2" then, replace all "create(" by "create2("

Its horrible.. but, works..

Answer (score 0):

MooTools version 1.4.3 solves this issue - you may download it from [Download MooTools 1.4.3](http://mootools.net/download)